# Class to class access, from ref class to gui class

Tags: .net, c++, class

how I can access controls of `Form` class from another simple class

Lets say
I have create new clr (c++ .net 2008)  windows application, & add a lable1 on it, (Form1.cpp & Form1.h created by default  having `namaspace tmp_beginInvoke_c`)

then I create a new b.h file & add a simple reference class b. like code below,

```
#include "Form1.h"

namespace tmp_beginInvoke_c_B {

 //using namespace tmp_beginInvoke_c;  //{error C2871: 'tmp_beginInvoke_c' : a namespace with this name does not exist,} namespace of Form1 in my project
 using namespace System;
 using namespace System::ComponentModel;

 public ref class b
 {
 public: 
  b(void)
  {

  }


  b(Form1^% guiForm)
  {
   //guiForm->ChangeLabel();
   //this->frm = gcnew Form1();
   this->frm = guiForm;
   this->frm->ChangeLabel();

  }

  int i;
  Form1 ^frm;

 };

}
```

I also add following in Form1.h

1. `#include "b.h"`
2. `using namespace tmp_beginInvoke_c_B;`
3. `b^ obj = gcnew b();   // this line in constructure`.

raising build error :-(

My target:-
       I want to pass reference of `Form1` created instance to all `b` class object, 
       `b` class object will call a function of `Form1` class randomly on event base.

if I say ore accuretely b class object will call `beginInvoke` of control on `Form1`.
something like

```
Thread^ t = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart((frm,&tmp_beginInvoke_c::Form1::ChangeLabel)); //which will call beginInvike of control
```

Answer (score 0):

As probably everybody before I do not understand the question.

But I would advise to separate declaration from implementation. Both classes reference each other so you probably need to use forward declaration for one of them, e.g. `ref class b;` in Form1.h. But you cannot access any member of this class including constructor before the real declaration is known.